# Proving diagonalizability of a matrix if eigenspaces do not intersect

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I have two eigenspaces $E_1$ and $E_{-1}$ (where $1$ and $-1$ are not necessarily distinct) of a matrix $A$ where I have found their intersection to be $0$, so they form a direct sum of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Is this enough to show that $A$ is diagonalizable?

If not, then should I show that the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity somehow? I do not have the specific values of the matrices, but I do know that $\forall v \in R^{n}$, $$(A + I)\vec{v} \in \ker(A - I)$$ and $$(A - I)\vec{v} \in \ker(A + I).$$

I haven't learned minimal polynomials in my course yet, so I cannot use them.

Please correct me if I am misunderstanding anything. I am new to linear algebra.

Comment: A correction to your first sentence: you seem to be implying that if two subspaces have a $0$ intersection, then they form a direct sum of a vector space.  However, this is not necessarily the case

Comment: Also, what do you mean by $V^n$?  Perhaps you meant to say "a vector space $V$", or simply "$\Bbb R^n$".

Comment: When you say $(A + I)\vec{v} \in ker(A - I)$, do you mean that "for every vector $\vec v \in V$, $(A + I) \vec v \in \ker(A-I)$"?

Comment: Yes, all three of those are what I intended to say. I will edit my post. If what I stated in your first comment is untrue, then I will most likely have to use the algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity approach?

Comment: Anyway, eigenspaces relative to distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent.

Comment: Eigenspaces corresponding to different eigenvalues *always* intersect trivially.  Diagonalizability of $A$ depends on the sizes/dimensions of *all* eigenspaces.

Comment: The eigenvalues are not necessarily distinct in this case, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Diagonalizability is equivalent to the space having a basis consisting of eigenvectors. If the space is a direct sum of eigenspaces, then it has a basis consisting of eigenvectors, so we have diagonalizability.

Comment: Does that not contradict the first comment by Omnomnomnom? Or are they saying that they have to add up to the vector space and also have a 0 intersection to be a direct sum?

Comment: No, it does not contradict it, because you are not asserting that the sum is the whole space, just that the intersection is trivial. (Also, if you have eigenspaces corresponding to the same eigenvalue and their intersection is trivial, then you are doing something wrong; either what you call “eigenspace” is not really an eigenspace, which should include **all** eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue; or they are not eigenvalues at all; or you did the intersection wrong). This is a mess.

Comment: Thank you, I will train more.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "where 1 and -1 are not necessarily distinct"? Doyou mean that the matrix could have its elements in a field of characteristic 2?

Comment: No, the eigenspaces are from eigenvalues 1 and -1, and these eigenvalues are not necessarily distinct, that is, the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue is not necessarily 1. Was my notation not correct?

Comment: It's not notation, it's terminology. When you say $r$ and $s$ are not necessarily distinct, what that means (to everyone else) is that you are allowing for the situation that $r=s$.